# ListView Builder is not returning any text when calling list

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-listview, dart-html

I've found that if I change my itemCount to a number it still doesn't work but if I change the itemCount & comment out the teamServices call there and in the column, it will display the text Hello.

So I'm thinking my problem is with this line of code here `final teamServices = Provider.of<TeamServices>(context);` because it does print in the console from the services page. Any help would be appreciated!

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_api/pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_api/services/team_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AppState());

class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppState({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_)=> TeamServices())
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
      );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo'
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage**

```
import 'package:firebase_api/services/team_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final teamServices = Provider.of<TeamServices>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Firebase'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[400],
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3, //teamServices.listTeams.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('Hello'),
          //  Text(teamServices.listTeams.length.toString()),
          //  Text(teamServices.listTeams[index].customer)
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**team_services**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_api/models/teams_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TeamServices extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String _urlBase =
      'test-ab11a-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com';

  final List<Team> listTeams = [];

  TeamServices() {
    getTeams();
  }

  Future <List<Team>> getTeams() async {
    final teamUrl = Uri.https(_urlBase, 'orders.json');
    final response = await http.get(teamUrl);

   // print(response.body);
    final Map<String, dynamic> obj = json.decode(response.body);

    obj.forEach((key, value) {

      final team = Team.fromMap(value);
      team.id  = key; //.toString(); // as int?;
      listTeams.add(team);

     });


   // print(listTeams[5].price);
    print(listTeams.length);
     return listTeams;
     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling an async function (`getTeams`) it the constructor of your service. Consequently it is very likely that the variable `listTeams` is empty when the widget is built.

In addition, you are not using correctly **ChangeNotifier** since:

- You are not notifying listeners of changes. You should add `notifyListeners()` after the loop on the json map.
- You are not listening to those changes. The provider is just doing what its name indicates, providing the service instance, that's it. You should then wrap your **ListView** in a widget that listens to changes, for example a **ListenableBuilder**

Take a look at the example on [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response!  It's appreciated.  I'm new to flutter and I was following a tutorial and ran into the error. I will research more on **ChangeNotifer** and attempt to understand it more clearly.  Adding `notifyListeners()` did get the results to show.  Thanks again!